# Problems with Wine audio

Tags: sound, wine

I can not find where the turn on jack in the audio tab in Wine. Help please.

[image: http://rghost.ru/50091693/image.png]

Comment: Wine only has drivers for ALSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine's audio stack was simplified years ago. They removed everything else and went with ALSA and tried to make that as compatible with Pulseaudio as possible. Why? Because it satisfies 99.99% of the modern desktop Linux users.

If you want to use JACK, you're going to need to manually route the audio around. I would assume anybody choosing JACK would know all about this side of things but here's the documentation on it, just in case: http://jackaudio.org/routing_alsa